# Terminal editor/pager that allows jumping to particular line based on external command or file?

Tags: linux, editor, less, terminal-multiplexer

(First asked on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591052/terminal-editor-pager-that-allows-jumping-to-particular-line-based-on-external-c).)

I'd like to script something so that an existing process viewing a listing file jumps to a particular line. The process might be `less` or `nano` or, if need be, another pager or editor. I would, if possible, rather not start a new process like executing `nano FILE +LINE` does. I also would like it to be more direct than using the `screen` copy buffer to manually enter the new line using nano's `Ctrl+_` shortcut.

For context, on a GUI system I can use `pluma FILE +LINE` and this will open the file in MATE's editor if it isn't opened yet, but will switch to the already opened file if it is already opened. I also have a way to assign a shortcut to a "Snippet" extension command which reads the line number from a file and executes the `pluma FILE +LINE` command. I'd like something similar for a terminal-based system, which I am only accessing across ssh and `screen`.

Comment: Why not `head -n 1000 filename | tail 24`? That would be pure SSH, no need for a screen at all

Comment: @Thomas Weller: That requires terminating the processes each time to update the view, or to amass unused processes in the background. I want it to automatically update the display and not do it by creating new processes. Refer to my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own sloppy [listing file pager](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/tractest/file/1700ee8f03de/traclist.pl) in Perl. It handles the signal USR1 which makes it update the lines displayed, taking information on what line to choose from a temporary file. This is superior to using Pluma as I mentioned in the question, because it will update its display automatically in the background. That is, without focussing the terminal window in which it runs. (I still allow writing into the line number file used for Pluma to make its search capabilities available somewhat easily.)